# MKAnnotationView not drawing transparent PNGs properly

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am having trouble getting my custom `MKAnnotationView` to render with proper alpha blending on its edges. As you can see from the following screenshot, the red and green dots have an ugly black edge that does not blend into the background, but the system-supplied user location (the blue dot, barely visible) does not.

[image]

The image is a transparent PNG and I have confirmed it's not the image's fault as it renders properly elsewhere.

I have set `opaque = NO` on the `MKAnnotationView` but it had no effect.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ha, well it went away on its own. I'm honestly not sure what I did but I wasn't even worrying about it, changing some other stuff around and all of a sudden it renders properly now.

****shrug****